# NVL and relational operator in where clause of db query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am learning SQL and using Oracle 11.  I am working with a criminal database and trying to get the criminals who have unpaid fee's.  My query is as follows

```
select first, last, charge_id, (fine_amount + court_fee) as "Total Amount Owed", NVL(amount_paid, null), (fine_amount + court_fee - amount_paid) as "Amount Owed", pay_due_date 
from crime_charges cc, criminals c, crimes
where crimes.crime_id = cc.crime_id and c.criminal_id = crimes.criminal_id and (NVL(fine_amount, 0) + NVL(court_fee, 0)) – NVL(amount_paid, 0 ) > 0;
```

There are null values in the database for amount_paid and fine_amount and court_fee.  Im trying to filter out there criminals who dont owe anything atm ie 
(fine_amount + court_fee) – amount_paid> 0

i keep getting an error saying 
ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
00920. 00000 -  "invalid relational operator"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 43 Column: 122

I haven't been able to get NVL to work in the where clause at all.  I have seen examples of where clauses using NVL but i dont see how they differ from my query.

Example:

```
SELECT fname, lname, manager_emp_id

FROM employee

WHERE NVL(manager_emp_id, -999) != 7698;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `–` instead of `-`.

Wait, what?

```
select dump('–') from dual;
Typ=96 Len=3: 239,191,189

select dump('-') from dual;
Typ=96 Len=1: 45
```

Comment: Thank you so much the issue was in fact the "-" vs "-". I copy pasted it from the pdf the teacher gave us never thinking about what the character was.

Answer (score 1):

First off i think you should avoid using a NULL-approach when creating your database since all the nulls are taking up alot of space. In most cases having NULLs in a databases is a bad implementation.

NVL(amount_paid, null) says following:
If amount_paid is 'null' set it as 'null'.

Im quite new to databases myself but that could be a issue, try setting NVL(amount_paid, 0) instead.

elsewise the usage of NVL is correct.

Comment: the teach actually wants null to appear if they criminal has not paid anything.  But you make 1 good point and that is that i probably dont need the NVL(amount_paid, null) in the select statement as the amount_paid is already null it basically shouldnt be doing anything.  But Im working with a database from our school book and it is using null values to make us learn how to use NVL.  The idea is you cant add a null value to some number and equate it to some other number.  Example fine_amount = 1000 court_fee = 25 amount paid = null.  The database would be adding 1000 + 25 - null > 0.

Comment: I believe you need to add a parentheses around the calculation like:
((NVL(fine_amount, 0) + NVL(court_fee, 0)) – NVL(amount_paid, 0)) > 0;

Comment: If your teacher wants `NULL` when there's no payment, use `NULLIF(amount_paid, 0)`. If `amount_paid` is zero the function will return `NULL`. For any other value, it will return `amount_paid`. Also heed the advice from the other answer about the long dash. That can happen, for example, if you paste in a query from a Word document.

Comment: The alternative to using NULLs would likely require much more space.  A NULL in Oracle requires 1 byte.  A super-relational design (or whatever it's called), would require extra tables and rows.  Even if the tables are incredibly sparse it wouldn't help much.

Comment: I heartily disagree that NULL's in a database is a bad implementation.